# How to prove that $\lim(\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}(\cos(|n!\pi x|)^{2k}))=\chi_\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is this called? Rationals and irrationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264889/how-is-this-called-rationals-and-irrationals)

Please help me prove, that
$$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\left(\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}(\cos(|n!\pi x|)^{2k})\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & \iff x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
0 & \iff x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

Seems very complicated, but it's on calc I. I've tried use series expansions of cos, but it don't lead to answer. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Please don't use too much advanced techniques.

Comment: is that $\pi$, or really $\Pi$?

Comment: just Pi = 3.1415...

Comment: +1 Nice question. Also, the absolute value isn't really necessary, since $\cos$ is an even function.

Comment: I know that I’ve answered this or a very similar question here before, but it may take a while to find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Baby Rudin has this as an example.

[image: See Baby Rudin page 145]

Comment: I don't understand still, why the lim lim is equal 0 for irrational x

Comment: because $cos(m!\pi x) < 1$ when $x$ is irrational, so if you raise it to large powers, it goes to 0.

Comment: Ok, now understand!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then there exists some $N$ such that for $n > N$, $n! \pi x$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$. Conclude that it tends to 1.

Show that if $x \not \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} [\cos (n! \pi x)]^{2k} = 0$.

Comment: So then x = p/q. When N > 2q, $2\mid n!\pi x$. Could You advice more about the second part?