# $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\lim_{k \to \infty}(\cos(n!\pi x)^{2k}))$

Tags: calculus

> Identify the function $f(x) = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}(\lim_{k \to \infty}(\cos(n!\pi x)^{2k}))$.

I was confused how to find this limit because cosine oscillates, so I didn't think it was possible to find the limit.

Comment: I haven't thought very hard about it but it might be good to break it into the cases of $x$ rational and $x$ irrational and consider sufficiently large (fixed) $n$ for the $k$ limit.

Comment: (So, it's the indicator function of the rationals?)

Comment: If $x$ is rational then eventually $n!x$ is an integer. If $x$ is irrational then $n!x$ is never an integer. From this you can figure out the properties of $|\cos(n! \pi x)|$ which give the result.

Comment: It's the characteristic function for the set of rational numbers.

Comment: This one is more interesting:
$f(x) = \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}(\lim_{n \to \infty}(\cos(n!\pi x)^{2k}))$

Comment: nevermind, the first limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling The first limit *does* exist if $x$ is rational. I don't think it exists if $x$ is irrational though.

Comment: either way $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}0 \quad & \text{if } x \text{ is irrational} \\  1 \quad & \text{if } x \text{ is rational} \\\end{cases}$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264889/double-limit-of-cos2nm-pi-x-at-rationals-and-irrationals?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Set $$D_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} \, : \, x=p/q \text{ with } q \text{ integer divisor of } n! \}. $$It is enough to notice that $$\lim_{m \to \infty} [\cos^2 (n! \pi x)]^m=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in D_n \\  0 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus D_n \end{cases}=f_n(x).$$Since $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n = \mathbb{Q}$$we have that $$\lim_n f_n(x) = \chi_{\mathbb{Q}} (x)= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$

Answer (score -1):

if x \in Q then x = p/q 
  then for some very large n  n!/q is even number therefore making 
      cos(n! \pi x) = 1
hence making the limit 1

else if x is irrational then (n!\pi x) is never \pi hence
     Z = (cos(n! \pi x) )^2 <1
 implies Z^k=1 
for all k

Comment: I'm sorry but i still don't know how to format

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation