# Show that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{j\to\infty}\cos^{2j}k!\pi x=0$

Tags: limits, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, rationality-testing

The Dirichlet function is defined as the indicator function of rational numbers. I have also seen this function described by:
$$f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{j\to\infty}\cos^{2j}k!\pi x$$
How does this limit act as the indicator, and how does it yield an answer if cosine is limited to Infinity?

Comment: What do you mean by "cosine is limited to Infinity"?

Comment: See (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264889/double-limit-of-cos2nm-pi-x-at-rationals-and-irrationals)

Answer (score 9):

Suppose $x$ is rational and $x=\frac pq$ for $\gcd(p,q)=1$. If $k\ge q$, $k!x$ will be an integer, so $\cos k!\pi x=\pm1$ and $\cos^{2j}k!\pi x=1$. Thus the function is 1 for sufficiently large $k,j$, so it evaluates to 1.

Suppose $x$ is irrational, then $k!x$ will never be an integer, so $|\cos k!\pi x|<1$ for all $k$. As $j\to\infty$, this variable being in the exponent yields $\cos^{2j}k!\pi x\to0$, so the function evaluates to 0.

Comment: Why is it k! instead of k?

Comment: @mtung If it were $k$, then $kx$ would not be an integer for sufficiently large $q$, and we would not be able to derive the result for rational $x$.

Comment: +1. Actually, for $k$ large enough, $k!x$ is an even integer, so we could say that $\cos(k!\pi x)=1$. But this, of course, does not add much to the proof.