# It is possible to calculate $\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\cos^{2m}(n!\pi x))$ when $x \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: limits

If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ then what will be the value of $\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\cos^{2m}(n!\pi x))$ ?

Approach: Well the expression $\cos^{2m}(n!\pi x)$ would basically mean $(\pm1)^{\infty}$ which is not defined. Then it is possible to calculate this limit somehow?

The answer was given as 2.

Comment: the $2m$ makes it always even powers, which makes it $1$

Comment: For sufficiently large $n$, $n!\pi x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, so $\cos(n!\pi x)$ is $1$ or $-1$. But since you are calculating the $m$th power of $\cos^2(n!\pi x)$, this is going to be $1$ for sufficiently large $n$, for all $m$. So the inside limit is $2$ for any $m\geq 1$, and then you are taking the outside limit of a constant function.

Comment: Look at    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264889/double-limit-of-cos2nm-pi-x-at-rationals-and-irrationals

Comment: @ArturoMagidin do we implicitly assume here that $n$ is always an integer?

Comment: @DatBoi: The use of $n$ and $m$ strongly suggest that, yes. The fact that we are using $n!$ (rather than a $\Gamma$-function) also tells us that it is almost certain $n$ is supposed to be an integer, and so that $m$ is as well.

Comment: @Alan indeed, no idea why I missed that, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break down the $\cos^{2m}(n!\pi x)$  into $(\cos^{2}(n!\pi x))^m$.  Then as soon as $n!$ starts to kill the denominator of $x$,  you get $(1)^m=1$, so yes the limit is 2

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put the square inside and the $m$ outside?

Comment: I suppose.  Tomato, tomato, does simplify the $\pm$.  I'lls witch

Answer (score 3):

For any finite $x$, $n!*x$ is always an even number if $n \to \infty$.

Thus, $(\cos{(\text{even multiple of}\, \pi)})^{even}=1$

Comment: $2|n! \;\; \forall\;\; n\in I^+-\{0,1\}$. So how is $n!\times x$ always odd?

Comment: Please see edit @DatBoi

Comment: "$n!∗x$ as $n \to \infty$" is always an even number, nice observation didn't consider that at all.